# Reading integers from file into 2-dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to read integers from two text files and assign the elements to two dimensional arrays (the purpose of the broader program is to multiply two square matrices together) but I think there's something about the array pointers that I'm not understanding. This is a code snippet from the problem part (mat1size/mat2size is determined by an earlier function that calculates the size of a matrix in the file and mat1file/mat2file is simply the ifstream file with the matrix in it):

```
const int size = sqrt(mat1size);

int** mat1 = NULL;
mat1 = new int *[size];

int** mat2 = NULL;
mat2 = new int *[size];

for (int row = 0; row != size; ++row)
{
    mat1[row] = new int[size];
    mat2[row] = new int[size];
}

for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j != size; ++j)
    {
        mat1file >> mat1[i][j];
        cout << mat1[i][j];
    }
}
```

When I run this code it prints -842150451 to the screen 32 times (for two matrices with 16 entries) instead of what should actually be stored in the arrays, which is the integers 1-32. I'm fairly new to pointers so I suspect it's something to do with pointers to arrays which is causing the problem but I've tried several things with no success.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is how mat1file and mat2file are defined earlier in the code:

```
ifstream mat1file, mat2file; string mat1loc, mat2loc;

cout << "Enter the file address of the first matrix: "; cin >> mat1loc;
cout << "\n Enter the file address of the second matrix: "; cin >> mat2loc;

mat1file.open(mat1loc); mat2file.open(mat2loc);

if (!mat1file.good() || !mat2file.good())
{
    cout << "Error: One or both file locations were not recognised. Program aborted. ";
    return 1;
}
```

The user input isn't really relevant for the problem, I have two files saved on my computer which each contain 16 numbers arrayed in the following format:

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16

I know that the file opening works as I have a separate function that checks the number of integers in an ifstream file and that returns the correct values.

Comment: What is the format of `mat1file` any why do you think C++ will magically know how to read it into a 2D array?

Comment: It's a simple .txt file containing 16 numbers in the form of a square matrix separated by spaces and newlines, the address of which is defined by the user at an earlier point in the program, declared using 'ifstream mat1file' and then opened with 'mat1file.open(<userinput>)'. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: How is `mat1file >> mat1[i][j];` working? `mat1file` isn't even defined in your example.

Comment: I've edited the question to show this. mat2file isn't used in the code above, I thought i'd try and get it to work for just one first.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`? **Your code have memory leaks.**

Comment: @Phil1970 Because I'm not allowed to haha. It's an exercise in using pointers and arrays